# OpenStreetMap offline tile extraction in php

Tags: php, leaflet, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude, offlineapps

I am trying to use OpenStreetMap tiles for offline use in our apps. I extract the tiles from a php script using the formulae given [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#PHP). But it is clearly visible that when I zoom in on the offline map, the bounds keep diminishing. I am using the below code:

```
$lon1 = -0.147315;
$lon2 = -0.123712;
$lat1 = 51.517074;
$lat2 = 51.505883;
for($zoom = 12; $zoom <= 18; $zoom++){
    $xtile1 = floor((($lon1 + 180) / 360) * pow(2, $zoom));
    $xtile2 = floor((($lon2 + 180) / 360) * pow(2, $zoom));
    $ytile1 = floor((1 - log(tan(deg2rad($lat1)) + 1 / cos(deg2rad($lat1))) / pi()) /2 * pow(2, $zoom));
    $ytile2 = floor((1 - log(tan(deg2rad($lat2)) + 1 / cos(deg2rad($lat2))) / pi()) /2 * pow(2, $zoom));
     
    for($xtile = $xtile1; $xtile<=$xtile2+1;$xtile++){
        for($ytile = $ytile1;$ytile<=$ytile2+1;$ytile++){
            ( $xtile + $ytile )% 2 == 0 ? $serverId = 'a' : $serverId = 'b'; //load balancing between 2 servers
            $url = "http://" . $serverId . ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" . $zoom . "/" . $xtile . "/" . $ytile .".png";
            $img = "central/" . $zoom . "_" . $xtile . "_" . $ytile .".png";
            file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
            echo $img . "saved <br>";
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to zoom in within the bounds of the initial zoom but I get errors like "tile not found". Is there something I'm doing wrong? Can someone please enlighten me?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not bulk download these tiles! Please read the [tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy). The OSM tile server runs on donated resources, please don't abuse it.

Comment: @scai I was only downloading for a very small area. I didn't think that was a policy violation. I am not planning to go for entire cities or countries with that code.

Comment: Okay, in this case it should be fine.